# Modelling event type objects

Tags: java, oop, events

We have an application that is composed of a number of independent components and sub-systems. We are looking at implementing a simple event logging mechanism where these components & sub-systems can log some events of interest. Events could be something like

- New account created
- Flight arrived
- Weekly report dispatched to management etc.

As you can see, the event types are heterogeneous in nature and the attributes that needs to be logged differs based on the event types. New account created event, for example, will also log the account-id, the name of the user who created the new account etc. Whereas, the flight arrived event will be logging the flight number, arrived at, arrived from etc.

I'm wondering what is the good way of modelling the event types and the attributes.

One option is to do it object oriented way - to have an AbstractEvent that will have some common attributes (timestamp, message etc) and then create a full hierarchy of classes underneath. The flight events, for example, can look like

```
abstract class AbstractEvent;
abstract class FlightEvent extends AbstractEvent;
class FlightArrivedEvent extends FlightEvent;
class FlightCancelledEvent extends FlightEvent;
```

The problem I see with this approch is that we have hundreds of events which will result in class explosion. Also, whenever we add a new event (very likely), we have to create a class and distribute the new package to all the components and sub-systems.

The second option I can think of is on the other end of the spectrum. Have a simple Event class that contains the basic attributes and wrap a map inside it so that the clients can populate any data they want. The code in that case will look something like this.

```
class Event {
    private timestamp;
    private eventType;
    private Map attributes;

    public Event ( String eventType ) {
        timestamp = System.nanoTime();
        this.eventType = eventType;
        attributes = new HashMap();
    }

   public Event add ( String key, String value ) {
        attributes.put ( key, value );
        return this;
   }
}
//Client code.
Event e = new Event("FlightEvent:FlightArrived")
         .add("FLIGHT_NUMBER", "ABC123")
         .add("ARRIVED_AT", "12:34");
```

While this is flexible, it suffers from inconsitency. Two components can log the FLIGHT_NUMBER key in two different formats (FLIGHT_NUMBER & FLGT_NO) and I can't think of a good way to enforce some convention.

Any one have some suggestions that can provide a nice compromise between these two extreme options?

Comment: how about using an enumeration as the key to your attribute map  And also as the eventType.  That would provide you with strong typing at least.

Comment: That would be stronger typing but only about 10% of the strength ha one would probably want. As soon as you decide to use a map for your content you lose most of the typing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Java event framework (see java.util.EventObject and the Beans framework) but the fundamental question you are asking is not connected with events. It is a design question, and it is this: do I use Java classes in my application to represent classes in my business domain?

It is clear that the different types of event are different "classes" of thing, but for maintainability reasons you are considering representing your business data in a map so that you don't have to write and distribute an actual class. If you take this to a logical extreme, you could design your whole application with no classes and just use maps and name-value pairs for everything - not just events. It would be a mess and you would be debugging it forever because you would have no type-safety whatsoever. The only way of finding what was in map would be to look up in some documentation somewhere what someone might have added to it and what type that object might be.

So, here is the thing - **you would not have actually have gotten rid of your class definition**.

You will have moved it into a Word document somewhere that people will have to refer to in order to understand what is in your map. The Word document will need to be maintained, verified and distributed but unlike the Java class, it won't be checked by the compiler and there is no guarantee that the programmers will interpret it correctly.

So I would say, if there is a class, put it in your code and then focus on solving the problems of distributing and versioning the Java classes instead of distributing and versioning Word documents.

I will mention versioning again as this is an issue if you might serialise the objects and restore them, so you need to think about that.

Some caveats:

1. If you are writing a piece of middleware software that routes events from one system to another system, it might be you don't need to know are care what the data is, and it might make sense to use a generic holder in this case. If you don't need to look at the data, you don't need a class for it.
2. You might get complaints from high-level designers and architects about the number of classes and the work they have to do in defining them compared with a map and name/value stuff. This is because putting classes (i.e., the real design) in Java is harder than putting them in a Word document. Easier, if you are high-level hand-waving type guy, to write something wishy-washy in Word that doesn't need to run or even compile and then give the real design work to the programmers to get working.

Answer (score 0):

> Can [someone] provide a nice compromise between these two extreme options?

No. There is no generic one-size-fits-all answer to this problem. You will have to find yourself a balance which fits the general design of your product. If you nail everything down, you will need thousands of classes. If you give a lot of leeway, you can get away with a few but you're paying your freedom with precision. See my blog post "[Designing a Garbage Bin](http://blog.pdark.de/2012/12/17/designing-a-garbage-bin/)"

Do you have shared attributes? As in: Do you expect to define attributes of events like you define classes right now with very tight-fitting semantics?

That would mean you have a simple event and typed attributes (i.e. `String value` simply isn't sufficient). You need formatting and validation for attributes or ... attributes themselves need to be classes.

If this is the case, you can use my type-safe map pattern: http://blog.pdark.de/2010/05/28/type-safe-object-map/

Answer (score 0):

Event type "explosion" is not a problem. In fact it is a desirable approach as it allows the components to be independent of one another. I wouldn't necessarily make all events inherit from a single superclass unless it gives you a lot of reusable code because it can cause dependencies to start proliferating.

I would put the event types in a separate project that will be a dependency of both the publisher and consumer.

What is your communication mechanism for these events between components? JMS? If so you could also consider making your messages XML and using JAXB.

I would definitely discount the map approach as it destroys any hope of polymorphism or any other oo niceties.